# many to many query mysql return duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, many-to-many, relational-database

i have 2 tables

1 resources

```
id  | name  | type
1   |  X    | form
2   |  YY   | post   
3   |  ZZ   | container
```

2 res_res

```
id  | parent_id | son_id

1   |  1        |  2
2   |  3        |  1
```

now i want to select resource.*, res_res.id of all resources related to resource id (1)

expected result

```
link_id | id | name | type |
1       | 2  | YY   | post |
2       | 3  | ZZ   | container
```

my query

1:

```
SELECT distinct r.* FROM `resources` as r
join res_res as l on (l.parent_id=r.id or l.son_id=r.id)
where l.parent_id = 2 or l.son_id = 2
```

this query run as expected and return result i want except that it doesnt include the id or the link (id from resource_resource table) , yet if i run this

2:

```
SELECT distinct l.id as link_id,r.* FROM `resources` as r
join res_res as l on (l.parent_id=r.id or l.son_id=r.id)
where l.parent_id = 2 or l.son_id = 2
```

this return so many duplicate rows; so what am i doing wrong ?

I thin the problem is that my join condition return both parent-id and son-id when row match, so duplicate happens, I need to put an if case in select so that I only select other field .

is there a better way to select all resources related to resource.id X and include the join id ?

i dont like using group_by cause it writes a temp. table which slow down my performance alot.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join condition is wrong as it matches against the son element even when parent is the one you need.

```
SELECT l.id as link_id,r.* 
FROM `resources` as r
CROSS JOIN res_res as l
WHERE (l.parent_id = 2 AND l.parent_id=r.id) OR (l.son_id = 2 AND l.son_id=r.id)
```

Comment: thanks yet this only returns the parent row also duplicated as many as its children count; example if I run it it will return row r.I'd = 2 as many times same row

Comment: Select l.I'd,r.* from resources as r cross join red_res as l on ( l.parent = 2 and l.son_id = r.I'd) or (l.son_id = 2 and l.parent_id  = r.id )  Works :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use a UNION instead:-

```
SELECT l.id AS link_id, l.son_id AS id, r.name, r.type
FROM `resources` AS r
INNER JOIN res_res AS l ON l.parent_id = r.id
WHERE l.son_id = 1
UNION
SELECT  l.id AS link_id, l.parent_id AS id, r.name, r.type
FROM `resources` AS r
INNER JOIN res_res AS l ON l.son_id = r.id
WHERE l.parent_id = 1
```

Comment: I think my problem is that I need if parent_I'd = 2 select son_id else if son_I'd  = 2 select parent_I'd this will remove the duplicats

Comment: That is what this is doing. The first select gets all the res_res records for id 1 where the parent is 1, while the other gets them where the son id is 1. Assuming unique records on res_res there should be no duplicates. It avoids an OR in the join clause which would be inefficient.